# Need help adding div style to php echo statement

Tags: php, variables, echo

```
<?php // case_status ( array )
$case_status_array = get_field( 'case_status' );
if ( $case_status_array ):
    foreach ( $case_status_array as $case_status_item ):
        echo $case_status_item['value'];
    endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

I need **$case_status_item['value'];** to be wrapped in a div so that I can style the output, how would I do that?

Comment: `echo '<div>' . $case_status_item['value'] . '</div>';` ?

Comment: Awesome, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string interpolation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to handle this nice and cleanly.

```
echo "<div>{$case_status_item['value']}</div>";
```

Another useful way, espicially with long formatted strings with multiple `'` or `"` is to use to output strings is to use [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
echo <<< HTML
  <span style='color:red;'>
    With heredoc syntax you do not have to escape " or '
  </span> 
  <div>{$case_status_item['value']}</div>
  <div>{$bar}</div>
  <div>{$foo}</div>
HTML;
```

Hope that helps,